# Generating APIs for an existing GAE application using Cloud Endpoints that has no need for supporting CRUD operations?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an existing app engine application written in JAVA (developed using GWT+GAE framework in Eclipse IDE) with methods that take input from client (browser) in the form of a String or numeric values, perform some server-side computations and return results in numeric, ArrayList formats back to the client. There is no need to create datastore entities etc.

So, if I wanted to expose these server-side functionalities via APIs to be consumed by mobile clients, can it be done easily using Google Cloud Endpoints support? Most Google Cloud Endpoint examples/tutorials that I found online seem to suggest that a persistence-capable entity class is a requirement. Is there a simple way to avoid this if we don't need to create and persist entities and support any CRUD operations in the application? Any pointers to examples will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your methods are already compatible to endpoints requirements, all you need to do is:

1. Put @Api on the class(es) where you choose to put your your API methods. e.g.

   @Api(name = "api_name",version = "v1")
2. If your methods have similar mandatory parameters, then put @ApiMethod with path to distinguish between APIs. e.g.

   @ApiMethod(name="doSomething", path="doSomething/{id}")
3. Put method parameters on the API Methods. e.g.

   @Named("mandatoryParam") double mandatoryParam,
   @Nullable @Named("optionalParam") String optionalParam

You are ready with your basic Endpoints API. You can [generate the android client code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients#generating_a_client_library_for_android) and start using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was a bit confused about why all the tutorials I came across seem to emphasize entity creation and persistence related operations only :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are no such restrictions. All you have to do is create a class and add some methods and annotations that describe the API. Incoming requests are translated to method calls and you can do anything you want in the method body.

The hello world example should be enough to get you started: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/hello_world